# The best way to secure form depending on javascript validation when javascript disabled

Tags: php, javascript, html, validation

So up to now i got my client side validation ready, But what if javascript disabled?...
I was thinking what can be the best method to make sure the data i get is valid:

1. For start i can also test the data on the server side but than what is the point with all the javascript validation.
2. HTML 5 got some validation features but limited browser support.
3. I was thinking about something with Ajax but can't put my finger for ajax solution yet.

So i will be very thankful to get some suggestions for solution **when javascript off.**

Comment: if disabled, tell them that the page will not work without it. A page without javascript is nothing.

Comment: The point of javascript validation is to reduce time the user spends on your form. The point of server validation is to make sure your data is valid and you don't get hacked. In other words, do everything on the server. JS validation is a nice cherry on the cake.

Comment: You certainly must do validation on server side. So, just implement this and never depend on client side validation!!!

Comment: validate even when javascript is enabled what if your js is changed using inspect element? see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php and learn php string functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Never trust user input.
2. Never trust user input.
3. Never trust user input.
4. Never trust javascript validation, which can be tampered with *very easily* since it executes on the browser. Consider it is part of the user input.
5. Never trust user input.

Server-side validation is **always** mandatory, whether there is javascript validation or not. Other than that, Ajax is just a funky name for dynamic javascript calls to URL's. No Javascript, no Ajax.

There is nothing else I can think of, besides HTML5 validation (which must **not** be relied upon either, as it can be circumvented as easily as Javascript validation).

Comment: Thank you for you answer Yak, If as i understand server side + client side?

Comment: @uBlankText As it was stated by other people too, Javascript validation is a nice-to-have for the comfort of the user (check for invalid input without the need for a round-trip to the server), Server-side validation is required, for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Even if JavaScript is turned on, it's still perfectly possible to manipulate a form to post information that you might not be expecting on the server-side. Server-side validation is **always** needed for data storage and manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Please remember this mantra:

> JavaScript validation is **good for the user**, but Server validation is **good for security**.

And this one too:

> User data is **always evil**.

In other words, *always* perform server validation, because at the end of the day you are dealing with user data that may have been tampered with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should always have BOTH validation client side (javascript) and server side (business object in your language of choice).

You absolutely cannot trust *all* users to use/leave client side alone.

Client side validation is to help the user stay sane so they are not posting-erring, try again, post-erring, try again. And you cut traffic to your server/objects as well. Everyone likes that.

But you *NEED* to have your server side do a final validation if you are serious about validation. If you ever can only pick one or the other (and if a client has js disabled...) you pick server side.

If you want a slight lessening of what seems like redundant validation, have your form ajax post/call to a validator that calls your BUSINESS LOGIC rules on the server but then when the final post occurs, it needs to run through the BUSINESS LOGIC rules again before you commit.

Comment: server side + client side :-)